# Discussing Lashon Harah with another witness

Tags: halacha, lashon-hara-slander, chofetz-chaim

I'm surprised the Chofetz Chaim doesn't discuss this:

If me and my friend saw someone do something bad or embarrassing, are we allowed to discuss it between ourselves?

I'd appreciate your thoughts, and sources even more.

Comment: It's definitely forbidden to fill in what the other might have missed. And who's to say you both noticed the same details? If you did, there wouldn't be much to discuss.

Comment: @shmosel The situation that I'm referring to was a funny one, so we wanted to laugh about it.

Comment: @ElonMusk It is not permissible to mock or denigrate someone, even without sharing new information amongst yourselves (see, for instance, [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Chafetz_Chaim%2C_Part_One%2C_The_Prohibition_Against_Lashon_Hara%2C_Principle_2.2.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Comment: The sefer covers all sorts of examples of where there's a productive purpose or outcome. Is it that you just want a good laugh at someone? Then goodness no. If it's "hey, this authority figure did/said something kind of weird to me behind closed doors, was I making it up or the only one?" ... that's a different story. (And even then, think carefully about who the right people who could do something about it.)